# GenerateDsl.mwe2 error if changing the Target Platform

Tags: eclipse, xtext, emf

I have a XText project where I have a gramair (DLS.xtext file).
I copied my XTExt project to an Eclipse workspace where I have changed the target platform, but I have included in this target platform the XText, XTend plugins).

After changing the Target Platform I see an error in GenerateDsl.mwe2.

[image: ;]

Comment: You need to give a little bit more context before anyone can give you a meaningful answer. The specific error message, platform version, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I added in the target platform:

[image]